# Is there any Kafka Go client which support transactions?

Tags: go, transactions, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I need to use a client library which support transaction in Kafka. I know that Java has transaction APIs to support transaction but I will prefer if these APIs would be available in Go. Please let me know if we have any stable library which I can use to write into multiple partition atomically.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is currently available. The `librdkafka` library is being updated currently to support it, and then from there the golang client will too.

Comment: Robin , Thanks for your time . What will be your input whether should i use c client for kafka or java client .

Comment: The C client is also based on `librdkafka`. If you need transactions now, you will need to use the Java client. Support for others, via `librdkafka`, is coming though.

Comment: Is there any update on this. Has any go library implemented transactions support yet for consumers?